# How can union-find algorithm be used with "real" data

Tags: algorithm, set

In the beginning of the Princeton algorithms course the Dynamic connectivity problem is presented (quick-find, quick-union). Here is how it's described:

> The input is a sequence of pairs of integers, where each integer
>   represents an object of some type and we are to interpret the pair p q
>   as meaning “p is connected to q.” We assume that “is connected to” is
>   an equivalence relation, which means that it is
>
> - Reflexive : p is
>     connected to p.
> - Symmetric : If p is connected to q, then q is
>     connected to p.
> - Transitive : If p is connected to q and q is
>     connected to r, then p is connected to r.

And it has one simple implementation called `quick-find`:

> One approach is to maintain the invariant that p and q are connected
>   if and only if id[p] is equal to id[q]. In other words, all sites in a
>   component must have the same value in id[].This method is called
>   quick-find because find(p) just returns id[p], which immediately
>   implies that connected(p, q) reduces to just the test id[p] == id[q]
>   and returns true if and only if p and q are in the same component...To
>   combine the two components into one, we have to make all of the id[]
>   entries corresponding to both sets of sites the same value, as shown
>   in the example at right.

My question is how can this be used for real objects? It works for integers, but what if I need to know whether the object `A` is connected to the object `B`, not if `3` is connected to `5`? One solution I can think of is to have an array of objects where each object's index in the array corresponds to the index of the array used for connectivity. For example:

```
   1   2   3   4   5
[ { } { } {A} { } {B} ]   <---- real data

   1   2   3   4   5
[  1   2   3   4   3 ]    <---- connections (3 and 5 have the same group id 3)
```

Is that how it's applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest would definitely work, but can become a hassle when the list of objects is mutated in some way (e.g. is sorted in different ways).

You can implement the mentioned `quick-find` method by extending your objects with the mentioned `id` property (or any other name).

For instance, if you have these objects (using Python syntax):

```py
a = { "num":  1, "code": "test" };
b = { "num": 15, "code": "house" };
c = { "num":  9, "code": "garden" };
d = { "num":  4, "code": "flower" };
e = { "num": 24, "code": "cat" };
```

Then add the `id` property to those objects (the syntax for such extension differs in many languages):

```py
a["id"] = 1 # extend the object with an additional property.
b["id"] = 2
c["id"] = 3
d["id"] = 4
e["id"] = 3
```

Then create a function that tells you whether two objects are connected, as described for `quick-find`:

```py
def are_connected(x, y):
    return x["id"] == y["id"];
```

The result of the following test would in this case be true:

```py
print (are_connected(c, e)); # True
```

#### Alternative: keeping the connections separate

If you don't want to mutate your original objects by adding the `id` property, you can create a separate map. Some languages can give you a unique identifier for each object. For example, in Python this identifier can be retrieved with the built-in `id()` function. If not available, you would use a unique property of your object which in the sample data would be the `num` property. So in Python:

```
conn = {}
conn[id(a)] = 1
conn[id(b)] = 2
conn[id(c)] = 3
conn[id(d)] = 4
conn[id(e)] = 3

def are_connected(x, y):
    return conn[id(x)] == conn[id(y)];

print (are_connected(c, e)); # True
```

#### The quick-union algorithm

In this approach you would not (always) store the same id for connected objects, but have them point to another (child-to-parent) in the same group of connected objects, with the root of that tree pointing to itself.

If then two objects need to be tested for being connected, you would find the two roots they are each connected to (by traversing via their ancestors to the top of the trees) and see if they share that root.

With a bit different sample data, and using the `id` property, it would look like this:

```py
a = { "num":  1, "code": "test" };
b = { "num": 15, "code": "house" };
c = { "num":  9, "code": "garden" };
d = { "num":  4, "code": "flower" };
e = { "num": 24, "code": "cat" };
f = { "num": 88, "code": "dog" };
```

Then add the `id` property to those objects (the syntax for such extension differs in many languages):

```py
a["id"] = a # it is a root, so a self-reference
b["id"] = a # same group as a
c["id"] = c # root of different tree
d["id"] = c # same group as c
e["id"] = c # same group as c
f["id"] = d # same group as c, but child of d
```

This can be represented like this:

```
           a             c
           |            / \
           b           d   e
                      /
                     f
```

The function that tells you whether two objects are connected, would now look like this:

```py
def are_connected(x, y):
    while x["id"] != x: # while not at the root
        x = x["id"] # go upward in tree
    while y["id"] != y: # same for y
        y = y["id"] # go upward in tree
    return x == y; # if root is the same: the original objects are connected
```

Note that you could also write it as a recursive function.

The result of the following test would in this case be true:

```py
print (are_connected(e, f)); # True
```

Comment: _Then add the id property to those objects_ - thanks, how to keep track of sets and join them then? it's possible to use `quick-find` implementation and to update `id` of all objects in a set, but this is inefficient since it has `O(n)` runtime complexity. The much better implementation `weighted quick-union` which works on the same data representation with array has `O(logN)` complexity, but I can't see how I can apply it to the approach you suggested

Comment: I added a section about the `quick-union` approach. `weighted quick-union` only becomes something to look at when you need to join different trees (i.e. join distinct groups of connected objects to become all connected to each other).  If you need clarification about that also, I would suggest to ask a new question.

Comment: thank you very much, this part _a["id"] = a # it is a root, so a self-reference_ is was missing. Can you also please tell whether there is any advantage of the approach I used in my question as opposed to the approach you're describing?

Comment: Near the end of your question you used an array to put your objects in, and thereby giving them a unique *index* in that array. Like I wrote in the start of my answer, that is fine. It is just that you must pay attention not to move objects around in that array, since their place in that array is their key. Having the keys *in* the objects themselves (or in the case of *quick-union*: having the parent references from one object to the next) makes it something more *belonging* to those objects. It is in the end a matter of opinion and taste.

Answer (score 1):

Short anwser: YES.

Longer answer: You have to map real object to integer.
One of methods to mapping is to use the same tables for both type of objects (as you said).

Most programming languages have built in mappings. For example C# have "Dictionary" class, c++ have "map" class.

You can also write your own mapping.